# How can I switch from "show" and "hide" to "fadeIn" and "fadeOut"?

Tags: jquery, html, show, fadein, fadeout

I want the content inside div ids (DIV1, DIV2 and DIV3) to show simultaneously every few seconds. I found the code here that does almost exactly what I want, but I want the transition between showing different DIVs to be somewhat gentler. I tried replacing show and hide with fadeIn and fadeOut with no luck. Any help appreciated.

```
$(function () {
    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');

    function showDiv () {
        divs.hide() // hide all divs
            .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
            .show('slow'); // and show it

        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

    showDiv(); // show first div    

    setInterval(function () {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 10 * 500); // do this every 10 seconds    
});
```

Comment: Would probably make sense to show us your code that isn't working instead of the code that is working

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post what you have tried.  At a glance, `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` should work, but they take certain arguments: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/